Trigger to update mailing address of contact record when billing street of account record is updated no compilation error but contact not updating
    public static void UpdateBillingAddress(Map<id, account> MapOFBillingAddresses)
    {
        list<contact> ContactBillingAdressUpdated = new list<contact>();
        set<id> NewSet = new set<id>();
        
        list<account> ListOfNewlyUpdatedAccounts = [SELECT id, BillingStreet FROM account WHERE id IN :NewSet];
        map<id, account> listOfMap = new map<id, account>();
        for(account acc : ListOfNewlyUpdatedAccounts)
        {
            listOfMap.put(acc.Id, acc);
        }

        list<contact> ListOfNewContact = new list<contact>();
        for(contact con : ListOfNewContact)
        {
            if(listOfMap.containsKey(con.AccountId))
            {
                account acc = listOfMap.get(con.AccountId);
                con.MailingStreet = acc.BillingStreet;
                con.AccountId = acc.Id;
                ListOfNewContact.add(con);
            }
        }

        if(ListOfNewContact.size() > 0)
        {
            update ListOfNewContact;
        }
    }


There are multiple things wrong with your code.

NewSet is empty (you initialize it to a new list, which is empty)

As a result, your query on Account is going to return no records (and you won't get into the body of the for loop to populate listOfMap)
You don't even need that loop though, you should just be using the Map constructor that takes a list of SObjects (Map<Id, MySObject> sobjMap = new Map<Id, MySObject>("<your query here>"))


You haven't given us enough information about what MapOfBillingAddresses is, but it seems likely that you don't even need to write a query on Account here. listOfMap may be able to be completely eliminated
Likewise, ListOfNewContact is empty (because you initialize it to a new list)

As a result, you don't get into the body of the for loop to update the Contact Mailing Address
Your Contact is already related to the Account, no need to set the AccountId again


The if(ListOfNewContact.size() > 0) check is worthless. It accomplishes nothing other than adding clutter to your code. Salesforce is smart enough to not perform the DML if the list is empty (doesn't even count against the DML statement limit)

The only potential query that it looks like you should have here is one based on Contact, rather than on Account. Given a map of Accounts, you could simply have a query with a filter like AccountId IN :myAccountMap in the WHERE clause. A query based on Account where you have a subquery for the related Contacts in the SELECT clause would also work (and potentially be easier to reason about).
About the only other things worth mentioning here are that:

This is simple enough that you could take care of it with a Flow rather than with a trigger
Your code style could use some improvement. Be consistent, use spaces between operators and operands (myList=new List<Something>(); is harder to read than myList = new List<Something>(); for most people). Use plural names for sets, lists, and maps. Method and variable names should start with a lowercase letter. Class and type names (List, Account, Id, etc...) should start with an uppercase letter. Make your variable names meaningful and descriptive (accountMapById is 100x better than listOfMap).


list<account> ListOfNewlyUpdatedAccounts = [SELECT id, BillingStreet FROM account WHERE id IN :NewSet];

NewSet is empty, therefore no records will be queried. The rest of your code has nothing to do.
In addition:
list<contact> ListOfNewContact = new list<contact>();
for(contact con : ListOfNewContact)

Is also an empty list, so even more nothing to do.
Instead, your code should look something more like this:
Account[] accounts = [SELECT BillingStreet, (SELECT MailingStreet FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id = :newAccounts];
Contact[] updatedContacts = new Contact[0];
for(Account accountRecord: accounts) {
  for(Contact contactRecord: accountRecord.Contacts) {
    if(accountRecord.BillingStreet != contactRecord.MailingStreet) {
      updatedContacts.add(
        new Contact(Id=contactRecord.Id, MailingStreet=accountRecord.BillingStreet)
      );
    }
  }
}
update updatedContacts;

Note that we don't need to check for an empty list before DML, as Apex does this for us.
